# Integration of mypy and QuickFix window

Tags: quickfix, filetype-python, python

I would like to have a keyboard shortcut to

- run mypy on the current buffer
- put the output in the QuickFix window

I only want mypy to run and populate the QF window on demand, not constantly. I do have ALE installed, but I've not been able to a) limit the QuickFix window to only mypy output b) be able to run it on demand and c) not have ALE populate the QF window with mypy comments when I'm using the QF window for other things.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answer using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

Create a `~/.vim/compiler/mypy.vim` file with the following content:

```
set makeprg=mypy
```

In your python session you can activate the compiler with the following command:

```
:compiler mypy
```

More information with [:help :compiler`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acompiler)

The `compiler mypy` command will run the `mypy.vim` file and set the make options to use the `mypy` compiler.

To check the current file you can then do:

```
:make %
```

The `make` command run the tool configured in `makeprg` and populate the `quickfix` list based on the output using the `errorformat` to identify the relevant information (file name, line number, error message).

More information with:

- [:help :make](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#%3Amake)
- [:help 'makeprg'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27makeprg%27)
- [:help 'errorformat'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27errorformat%27)

Like @Friedrich mention you can associate the `make %` to a shortcut with:

```
nnoremap <F7> <cmd>make %<cr>
```

Comment: OP asked for a keyboard shortcut, that would be e.g `:noremap <F7> <Cmd>make %<CR>`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, really helpful. What I ended up doing, inspired by [@Vivian De Smedt's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/44016/10604), was:

In `.vimrc`

```
autocmd BufRead *.py set makeprg=mypy
nnoremap <leader>m :silent make %:S <Bar> copen<CR>
```

In `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.mypy]
error_summary = "False"
```

That does exactly what I need. Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you found Vivian's answer helpful, consider upvoting it. That's how we say "thank you".

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Self-answering is 100% fine; when your self-answer builds substantially on another user's answer, it is best to link to that answer. Upvotes can and _should_ be used to indicate technical accuracy and quality in the answer (the fact that you were able to make good use of the answer is a positive indicator). Please vote!